# Specifying CSS class of a Zend_Navigation li element

Tags: php, css, zend-framework

I can't seem to find where to specify the CSS class of the list items for rendering a Zend_Navigation object. I know you can set the class of the ul tag via the navigation menu view helper and the class of the anchor via a page attribute...but not the li tag containing the anchor.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing an extension to the Navigation Menu View Helper included with the zend framework. See my most recent post at http://www.zendcasts.com/forum/topic/97/integrating-acl-with-zendnavigation-using-view-partials-for-rendering/ if you're interested.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your own view script to customize your HTML output. There is currently no direct way to change the class of the `li` element.

```
$this->navigation()->menu()->setPartial('yourpartialview.phtml');
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually looked into using partials, but the only problem is Zend_Navigation does not take ACL into account this way, which is something that I need.

Comment: No? Does that mean the view script gets passed all the menu elements - even the forbidden ones?

Comment: That's correct, if you take a look in Zend/View/Helper/Navigation/Menu.php, I believe the ACL logic is in the _renderMenu method. When you have partials enabled, it does not perform that logic and throws all menu elements to the partial view.

Comment: Hmmm... that stinks. Can you write a custom plugin? I know the `liStyle` option has been requested, but that may or may not take a while...

Comment: Would love to, but I think for time's sake, I'll just change my CSS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Get the id name of menu, in this case #tabcontainer then use #tabcontainer li to modify

```
    #tabContaier_main ul{
    overflow:hidden;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    height:35px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
}
#tabContaier_main li{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Few years late but add a 'class' option to a navigation page and set addPageClassToLi

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->addPageClassToLi(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to use jQuery to set the class for the links `<a>` and list `<li>` elements. But it worked fine for me.

```
$('#nav-container > ul > li > a').attr("class","ui-state-default ui-corner-bottom");
```